# Tizen .net application. How to access device hard buttons

Tags: tizen, tizen-sdk, xamarin.tizen

I am working on a Tizen .net application for wearable devices.
I cannot find information on how to gain access to the device hardware such as the menu or back button.
I have found how to access the hardware and software bezel in the Wearable CircularUI documentation noted below.

```
https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/guides/.net-application/application-management/applications/watch-application
```

There appear to be at least a few other references to this for native or web applications, but I could not find any API for .net applications.
Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Application can't handle `home` hardware key
only can handle `Back` hardware key.
if You use Xamarin.forms, you can override [OnBackButtonPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms) method to handle `Back` hardware key

Here is guide to use Bezel event
https://samsung.github.io/Tizen.CircularUI/guide/IRotaryEventReceiver.html

Comment: I see. When using Tizen.Net hardware buttons are not part of Tizen API but rather they are abstracted and handled as part of Xamarin Forms API.

Comment: No, you can handle `Back` hardware buttons if you use Tizen.API. https://samsung.github.io/TizenFX/API4/api/ElmSharp.EvasObject.html#ElmSharp_EvasObject_BackButtonPressed

Comment: So this is TizenFX API, but within it is ELM Sharp API which is beta?
I would avoid any non production ready code at this point.

Is there some explanation the relationship between Tizen for Xamarin vs Tizen FX vs ELMSharp.  I am genuinely confused

Comment: For 3rd party developers, Tizen supports Native API, Web API, and C# API.
Native API is consisted of Tizen Sub-system API (AppFw, Content, Multimedia, Network, EFL (UI FW), etc) + Open Source (libc, glibc, OpenSSL, Curl, ..) 
To support better dev environment, C# was adopted recently.
"FizenFx" could be the wrapper of Tizen Sub-system API.
"EFLSharp" is beta(temporal) version of EFL UI FW.
Newly designed UI FW will replace "EFLSharp", but, deprecated EFLSharp will be maintained for several release.
Xamarin.Forms is for cross-platform UI programming.